# Ripple effect for icons in android?

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to add a ripple effect to `ImageView`. I got to know that you can emulate the ripple effect on touch of the image view if you add the following background to it.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

I dug deeper to see what it really contained (Checked in side platform v21). It actually points to this file called `item_background.xml`.The contents of this file are :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

All of these lead to a bunch of 9 patch images. Where is the part that adds the ripple effect to all of this?

Answer (score 0):

That file is the 'old' `item_background`, which shows the yellowish images when pressed/focused etc, as known from Android 2.

Instead, have a look at the file `item_background_material.xml`, which can be found in `{ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/android-22/data/res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@id/mask">
        <color android:color="@color/white" />
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: But I tool that file name platforms->android-21. How can it be old?

Comment: Typo in the above sentence. *took

Answer (score -1):

Use this library. Its very simple and all u need it`s to put your image view to container. https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect